# How to find the distance between two pixels in c#?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to implement an image resize algorithm in c#. Here is what i think: I find the distance between two pixels and if it is a zoom, i increase the distance between all pixels by some value depending on the resize values. The question is, how can i find the distance between two pixels so that i can play with it? I see that pixels are color variables and i looked at the member functions and public variables of Color class, but i cannot find anything useful.

Looks like i have to find distance between two points, but how can i get the coordinates of the pixels?

Thanks

Comment: How can **you** find the distance between two points in [Cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) ?

Comment: Do you have *any* code? Do you know how to find the distance between two points on a plane? Do you think it has anything to do with color?

Comment: @panpa, how can you *conceivably* have two pixels and not know where they are located?

Comment: @L.B i am new to image processing in c#, and here is what i think: When i use getPixel() function of a bitmap, it returns a color and i cannot find a way to get the coordinates of a Color object

Comment: @panpa: Aren't there already image resizing algorithms in .NET?

Comment: @dreamlax yes there are but i want to understand how it works

Comment: @panpa, a pixel indicates a color.  A color does NOT indicate a specific pixel.  (what if it's a bitmap of all white pixels?)

Comment: @panpa When you call `getPixel` you give the arguments `X` and `Y`. this is the coordinate of your pixel :)

Comment: @panpa: The `Color` class doesn't mention coordinates because these aren't properties of a colour. Just like you can't tell the time or the size of a file with the `Color` class.

Comment: @L.B thanks, that was what i have been trying to find out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the coordinates of the pixels the distance is to root sum squared:

```
double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.Pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```

Comment: thanks, but what i really wonder is, how can i get the coordinates of the pixels?

Comment: What pixels are you looking for?

Comment: the pixels of the picture

Comment: The pixels start at (0,0) and ends at (width-1,height-1). It's kinda hard if you ask something, but means something else. It would help if you post an image to visualize it.

Comment: Its just apply this equation, its the module of the vector that reach the two points!

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen thank you, this is what i have been wondering